# Disallow alphanumeric characters in numeric template literal types

Tags: typescript, types

```js
interface Message{
   Code: `SLA${number}`;
}
```

The type definition attempts to constraint string values to the form of `SLAXXX`.
With `SLA123` and `SLA01000` being valid values.

A negative sign is part of a number, thus input such as `SLA-102` or `SLA0x10` still pass the check.

How can we enforce the code field to have a prefix of SLA followed by only numeral characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a helper function :

```
type Digit =  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;

type OnlyDigits<S> = S extends '' ? unknown : S extends `${Digit}${infer Tail}` ? OnlyDigits<Tail> : never;

type Code =  `SLA${Digit}`;


function code<S extends string>(s: `SLA${S & OnlyDigits<S>}`): Code {
  return s as Code;
}

const foo = code(`SLA0000011`);
const bar = code(`SLA000x011`); // KO
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgczsKBeKUAMUA%20UCMuUATEQMxEAsRArEQGxEDsRAHEQJwDcAUD6JCgB5AHYAbEPCTAAzgB4AygD40UBVAgAPYBBEATGVADkRqAH4oAVxEBrEQHsA7iKgAuNRu26DUAAYASAG8pZABfILgRADMIACcoABUAQzgxUN9zYXFJRGR5ZNSVdxEIADc43n5waABhez1odD8FABkAQSCQ4HTKnijrAGNgOHsXAfqIRU8dfUMZYFjIhCUAChl3X1aOwPUAMiyJLvlldIBKdzqGqECeDFiIYEtYl0Mkw0uIXlC%20cZF5qCi9nsqnGDRWm3amChUPw%20F8py4UAA9EjhABpHi-f4AIyS8XQoIg4K20M0mFh8MRKKgaKEQA)

The helper function here is required to infer the generic.